# Stripe Subscription:Customer Creation

Tags: spring-boot, stripe-payments

I am working on stripe subscription integration in my Spring Boot application. I am able to successfully redirect user to the checkout page and process the payment. I am working on the no-code application and the business model of my app is to charge the customer for each project created. Each time the user process the payment I am saving the customer-id and subscription-id in the database of the project but in order to subscribe to the same customer for the next project I have to create a new customer in the Stripe account and then the same flow continues. So, is it possible to subscribe the same customer for a new project without creating the customer in the stripe account?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. You just need to pass the existing customer Id when creating a checkout session.

That's what I'm doing:

- If a user doesn't have a stripe customer created, I create one and store the customer id against my internal user id (I also send the user id in the customer metadata to stripe, so it's easy to correlate them, as they may use different email addresses for payment).
- If a customer already exists for the current user, I just use that one.

I'm using typescript, the concept is the same:

```js
// uid is my internal user id

const customerId = getOrCreateCustomer(uid);

const newSession: StripeType.Checkout.SessionCreateParams = {
    customer: customerId,
    mode: 'subscription',
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    customer_update: {
        address: 'auto',
        name: 'auto',
        shipping: 'auto',
    },
    subscription_data: {
        metadata: { uid }, // store uid in subscription metadata as well
    },
    line_items: [
        {
            price: priceId,
            quantity: 1,
        }
    ],
    success_url: successUrl,
    cancel_url: cancelUrl,
};
```

Comment: Suppose user created a Project 1 and subscribed to xyz plan I saved the customerid and subscriptionid and each time the user want to upgrade the plan I can use that customer id to upgrade it but the same customer created another project “Project 2” and both the project can have different subscriptions suppose plan PQR then how should I handle it without creating new customer in the stripe account

Comment: Well I think on the long run, you should store the customer Id against a user, not a project. I guess what you can do now is: when a user creates `Project 2` you could check if that user has other projects and if it does, pick a customer id from the other ones (the 1st one) and reuse that customer id.

Comment: okay great and if the subscription fails in the next month then which webhook do you suggest me I was thinking of "customer.subscription.updated" and here checked if the status is unpaid I degraded the plan but in the docs they are mentioning to listen to "invoice.payment_failed"

Comment: I personally use only to `subscription.updated` and `subscription.deleted` and all the secure APIs check if the current user has an `active` subscription in stripe.